# How to code having in mind the screen resolution of each user?

Tags: html, css

I made my web design in Figma setting it to **1440px** x **1024px**.
(here is the link if that helps to see what I mean https://www.figma.com/file/IlSDcBbvr4nFp83p0jtndR/Bohhi-Portfolio?node-id=2%3A2)

Now that I want to code and style it I'm confused about it.
How can I position my objects in relation to the design and screen resolution of my PC and every other user?

Can I make it so that the code fits the design?

Thank you!

Comment: The [responsive design page at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Responsive_Design) might be a good place to start.  The gist-- use a combination of relative units (such as percentages and rems), media queries, and other responsive techniques to guide the browser as to how to alter the layout and the viewport grows/shrinks.  Web is not print-- there are myriad different screen and window sizes on which your site may be rendered.  Your best bet is not to fight this, but to embrace.

Answer (score 2):

Try checking out `@media query` for creating responsive layouts:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Explanation Edit:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

width: 100%;


}
```

For example, you can use it to ajust your preferred lyaout on devices with different screen `widths` (Example: Phone).

When a condition is `true` (Example: device screen is maximally 768px width) the following css property will be used (Example: `width: 100%;`). In this way you can create different content layouts and properties for PC users and Phone users.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the answer. I don't understand it.  I cant code it to the initial size of the design and then @media it to the 100% or auto resolution?

Comment: @bohhi you can use `max-width` and `min-width`. By using this, you’re looking at the dimensions of the screen a user is viewing your website from. You can use your current design for the dimensions you designed on and something like chrome dev tools to test other screen viewports/resolutions. https://anexia.com/blog/en/chrome-dev-tools-explained/

Comment: @bohhi applied explanation in the edit